How to Get Individual Responses for Each Insert in ODataBatch Execution Using Simple.OData.V4.Client?
I am using the Simple.OData.V4.Client library (version 6.0.1) to insert multiple accounts in a batch operation. Here’s the code I currently use:
var batch = new ODataBatch(client);

var accountsToInsert = new List<Account>
{
    new Account { AccountId = "12345", Name = "Test Account 1", Type = "Corporate" },
    new Account { AccountId = "67890", Name = "Test Account 2", Type = "Personal" },
    new Account { AccountId = "11223", Name = "Test Account 3", Type = "Business" }
};

// Add each account insertion to the batch
foreach (var account in accountsToInsert)
{
    batch += c => c
        .For<Account>()
        .Set(account)
        .InsertEntryAsync();
}

// Execute the batch operations
await batch.ExecuteAsync();

The issue I am facing is that batch.ExecuteAsync() throws an exception if any operation in the batch fails, but it only includes details for the first error encountered. If there are multiple errors (e.g., validation errors for different accounts), I can't retrieve information about all of them.
My Question:
How can I capture the individual responses or exceptions for each insert request in a batch using Simple.OData.V4.Client?
What I Have Tried:

Checked the library documentation for examples of handling individual responses in a batch, but didn't find a clear solution.
Investigated the source code and noticed that batch.ExecuteAsync() only throws the first error encountered.

Is there a way to process individual responses within a batch or extract details for all failed operations?
Environment:
Library: Simple.OData.V4.Client v6.0.1
Framework: .NET 6.0
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
